# Use period_range to generate new rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to generate new rows from a data frame using a start date and number of months. See below for example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'b'],
                   'start': ['5/6/2021', '5/20/2021'], 
                   'periods': [1, 12],
                   'MRR': [400, 380]})

df
```

| ID | start | periods | MRR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5/6/2021 | 1 | 400 |
| b | 5/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |

Ideally, I'd use the `pd.period_range` similarly to the example below, but not sure how to apply to the DataFrame/Columns:

```
prd = pd.period_range(df.loc[0,'start'], periods=12, freq='M')
prd = pd.Series(1, prd)
prd

2021-05    1
2021-06    1
2021-07    1
2021-08    1
2021-09    1
2021-10    1
2021-11    1
2021-12    1
2022-01    1
2022-02    1
2022-03    1
2022-04    1
```

Either way, the resulting DataFrame would look like:

| ID | start | periods | MRR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5/6/2021 | 1 | 400 |
| b | 5/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 6/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 7/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 8/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 9/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 10/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 11/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 12/20/2021 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 1/20/2022 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 2/20/2022 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 3/20/2022 | 12 | 380 |
| b | 4/20/2022 | 12 | 380 |

Comment: how big is your real dataset and do you a maximum number in periods?

Comment: @Ben.T, 255k rows. max is probably 24, but vast majority either 1 or 12.

Comment: Of 255k rows, 250k are 1 period, with ~5k at 12, and a negligible amount between 2-11. The use case is a recurring revenue build, on invoice-level data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas-multiindex-from-frame) using the `start` and `periods` values to create the ranges:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.set_index('ID')
        .apply(
        lambda r: pd.period_range(r['start'], periods=r['periods'], freq='M'),
        axis=1)
        .explode()
        .reset_index(),
    names=['ID', 'start']
)
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', '2021-05'),
            ('b', '2021-05'),
            ('b', '2021-06'),
            ('b', '2021-07'),
            ('b', '2021-08'),
            ('b', '2021-09'),
            ('b', '2021-10'),
            ('b', '2021-11'),
            ('b', '2021-12'),
            ('b', '2022-01'),
            ('b', '2022-02'),
            ('b', '2022-03'),
            ('b', '2022-04')],
           names=['ID', 'start'])
```

Convert `start` to a Monthly with [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html#pandas-series-asfreq) then [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) with the MultiIndex:

```
df['start'] = df['start'].asfreq('M')
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'start']).reindex(midx).reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
   ID    start  periods  MRR
0   a  2021-05        1  400
1   b  2021-05       12  380
2   b  2021-06       12  380
3   b  2021-07       12  380
4   b  2021-08       12  380
5   b  2021-09       12  380
6   b  2021-10       12  380
7   b  2021-11       12  380
8   b  2021-12       12  380
9   b  2022-01       12  380
10  b  2022-02       12  380
11  b  2022-03       12  380
12  b  2022-04       12  380
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to loop through `df` to populate a new dataframe.

```
prd_list = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    prd = pd.period_range(row['start'], periods=row['periods'], freq='M')
    prd_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': row['ID'], 'start': prd, 'periods':row['periods'], 'MRR': row['MRR']})
    prd_list.append(prd_df)

output = pd.concat(prd_list)
```